# Save a data frame to a file addressing by name

Tags: r, function, dataframe, save

I have a data frame and a text variable containing the name of this data frame:

```
adsl = data.frame(a=2, b=7, w=17)
ds_name = "adsl"
```

I want to save my data frame from the workspace to the file named "dest_file". The code should be wrapped into a function get_r() 
with the data frame name as an argument:

```
get_r(ds_name="adsl")
```

So I need to avoid using the explicit name "adsl" inside the code.

The following works almost correctly but the resulting data frame is called "temp_dataset", not "adsl":

```
get_r = function(ds_name){
    temp_dataset = eval(parse(text=ds_name))
    save(temp_dataset, file = "dest_file")
}
```

Here is another option which works wrong (the text string is being saved, not the data frame):

```
get_r = function(ds_name){
    save(ds_name, file = "dest_file")
}
```

What should I do to make R just execute

```
save(adsl, file="dest_file")
```

inside the function? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
save(list = ds_name, file = "dest_file")
```

The `list` argument in `save()` allows you to pass the name of the data as a character string.  See `help(save)` for more.